# Video rom part of iomem usage

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, drivers, memory, framebuffer

Given some x86_64 linux stock kernel running one single GPU embedded into whatever pci-e extension board.

---

cat-ing `/proc/iomem`, I can realize that some space is reserved in RAM and associated to the *Video ROM*.

1. Can I rightly assume that this is nothing but an exact copy of the BIOS (or equivalent) code for dealing with whatever *legacy* VGA device plugged into the ISA bus or whatever PCI device capable of decoding *legacy* VGA IO and/or MEM ?
2. Why is this code copied into RAM ?
   In order to allow faster access times?
   In order to keep it runable after kernel will have switched into protected mode?
3. Can I righly assume that this code will **only** be used as long as whatever in-kernel dedicated framebuffer driver (fbcon, vgafb, vesafb…) does not take precedence  ?
4. In case whatever framebuffer driver is made available, can this code be of later use in the lifetime of the running kernel ?
   If not then why the linux kernel does not, at boot time, simply get rid of that region when freeing unused memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not quite. `iomem` entries describe physical address uses; system RAM is marked as such, anything else describes ranges of addresses which aren’t used for RAM. The “Video ROM” entry points to the actual ROM (well, flash in practice). On x86 it is mapped on systems using a BIOS or CSM; systems booted through UEFI might not have it.

   You’ll see that on x86 it’s always mapped at 0xC0000:

   ```
   $ sudo cat /proc/iomem|grep "Video ROM"
   000c0000-000cfdff : Video ROM
   ```

   That’s where the video BIOS has always been mapped, and various (old) pieces of software need it to be there.
2. It is typically *not* copied into RAM. (It used to be, into “shadow RAM”, but that’s not done any more.)
3. On current systems, the code isn’t used (it used to be, in a limited number of scenarios, but as far as I’m aware it isn’t any more, except by [`vesafb` on 32-bit x86](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/video/fbdev/vesafb.c)).
4. The kernel doesn’t need to get rid of it, it doesn’t take away any memory and it lives in a range of addresses which is ignored in any case (the lower part of the physical address space is effectively unused on x86).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Your answer leading to some additional question : What code is responsible for display management before whatever framebuffer driver can take this in charge ?

Comment: In other words, what is the magic allowing the display of early printks ?

Comment: And in case they would only be buffered until some fb-driver being made available, how can some stack dump be displayed in case of early boot segfault ?

Comment: Do you mean [`vgacon`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/video/console/vgacon.c)? That takes care of the console if `fbcon` or something better isn’t available. It doesn’t use the video ROM, it drives the VGA hardware directly.

Comment: Hmmm! Do you explictily mean that from boot time = 0 nothing can be displayed before whatever in-kernel vga (or better) driver is successfully initialized ? (I of course do not include what is achieved on behalf of the bootloader)

Comment: No, I explicitly mean that `vgacon`, among others, can take care of the early messages and doesn’t use the video ROM.

Comment: My main point is that even for early printks, even on x86 PCs booting using BIOS, the video ROM isn’t needed, and the code it contains doesn’t run after boot.

Comment: ACK! And… fair enough! And thanks!

Comment: Ha! Well : NACK in fact. I discover an option for the nvidia proprietary drivers : *"NVreg_UseVBios : Enable or disable the use of the video BIOS int10 code"* defaulting to enabled.

Comment: On current NVIDIA drivers? AFAICT even the 390 legacy drivers don’t have that option. If memory serves the option didn’t have any effect on systems booted with UEFI GOP anyway.